# unable to define getElementById variables

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update number of people connected to the site by changing html element using javascript. For some reason if I set a variable on it, it does not work, but if I do it raw way (w/o variable) it works fine.

```
var users = document.getElementById('users').innerHTML;
users = connection.users;
```

↑ Doesn't Work

```
document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = connection.users;
```

↑ Works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because you are setting the innerHTML to the variable which isn't an object.

Doing this should work:

```
var users = document.getElementById('users');
users.innerHTML = connection.users;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the value assigned to `users` is a string - assigned by value, i.e. copied. It is *not* a stay-alive reference to the `innerHTML` property of an element.

If you want to use a variable, assign it as the element, not its HTML.

```
var users_el = document.getElementById('users');
users_el.innerHTML = connection.users;
```

In JavaScript, complex objects are copied by reference, whereas simple data types are copied by value, as in your case.

Comment: Everything is pass by value in JavaScript. But objects are reference-type values, so the value that is passed *is* a reference. That is different from pass *by* reference though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: Interesting. I was unaware of this distinction. Isn't the practical implication the same? The result is the result of the assignment is a reference. Happy to be educated!

Comment: Check out the link if you haven’t already. There is a big difference though. In a true pass by reference language, this would be possible: `var a = 42; var b = a; b = 21; /* a is now 21 */`. Basically “pass by reference/value” describes the relationship between variables and parameters, irrespectively of their values. *but* with reference-type values you can *simulate* pass by reference to some degree (often also called “pass by sharing”).